# jQuery Post is returning an error when trying to POST to a SOAP endpoint

Tags: jquery, servicenow

I am trying to POST to a Service Now URL from a HTML page. I am unable to do it. I would request someone to help me in this.

```
<html>
<body>
<button onclick="createRecord()">Create Soap</button>


<script src="jquery-1.6.4.js"></script>
<script language="javascript">
function createRecordCallback (xmlHttpRequest, status) {

  var sys_id = $(xmlHttpRequest.responseXML).find('sys_id').text();
  var tex = $(xmlHttpRequest.responseXML).text();
  if (status == "success") {
     var sys_id = $(xmlHttpRequest.responseXML).find('sys_id').text();
     alert(sys_id);
  } else {
     alert('error page'+sys_id+'is the sys id');
  }
}
function  createRecord() {
   var sel = '';
   var desc_field = 'comments';
     var instance = 'abc.service-now.com';
     var table = 'incident';
     var soapMessage = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>';

     soapMessage += '<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:inc="http://www.service-now.com/incident">';
     soapMessage += '<soapenv:Header/><soapenv:Body><inc:insert>';
     soapMessage += '<short_description>' + 'Incident Created' + '</short_description>';

     soapMessage += '</inc:insert></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>';


     $.ajax({
       url: "https://abc.service-now.com/incident.do?SOAP",
       type: "POST",
       dataType: "xml",
       username: "admin",
       password:"admin",
       data: soapMessage,
       complete: createRecordCallback,
       contentType: "text/xml; charset=\"utf-8\""

   });
   alert(soapMessage);
}
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

I am posting to a SOAP Endpoint, https://abc.service-now.com/incident.do?SOAP. I am trying to use insert method of that WebService.

Just a note, a very similar code is working in a chrome extension to the same endpoint.

Thank you!

Comment: Is the server on a different domain? If so, is it returning proper CORS headers?

Comment: Thanks Kevin, the HTML page that I posted is a standalone HTML on my computer.
How do we find if its returning proper CORS header?

Comment: CORS has issues when running as local html.  Try putting the file on a web server.

Comment: I assume you resolved this, perhaps answer your own question for the benefit of others :)